How do I make a navigation drawer open another website link or page?
There are tons of tutorial videos about how to create navigation drawers, but I want to know how to actually make it function. I figured out how to make the navigation menu, but when I click each option, it doesn't do anything or move to another page. Please help me re-direct the user to a website from my app or another page. I am using android studio, please help!
I want the menu to have:
About Us -> re-directs to another page for information
Contact Us -> re-directs to another page for information
Website -> re-directs to another website
Facebook -> re-directs to another website
Copyright -> re-directs to another page for information
I am using the Navigation Drawer Menu. I tried creating fragments and layouts, but it doesn't work. Whenever I click the app closes and says "stop working". I am using Javascript + XML.


package com.example.a1611kjvbible;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import ui_navigation.AboutFragment;
import ui_navigation.ContactFragment;
import ui_navigation.CopyrightFragment;
import ui_navigation.FacebookFragment;
import ui_navigation.HomeFragment;
import ui_navigation.WebsiteFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,b11,b12,b13,b14,b15,b16,b17,b18,b19,b20,b21,b22,b23,b24,b25,b26,b27;

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ImageButton buttonDrawerToggle;
    NavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        buttonDrawerToggle = findViewById(R.id.buttonDrawerToggle);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        buttonDrawerToggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawerLayout.open();
            }
        });
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull MenuItem item) {

                int id = item.getItemId();
                item.setChecked(true);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                if (id == R.id.nav_Home) {
                    replaceFragment(new HomeFragment());
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_About) {
                    replaceFragment(new AboutFragment());
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_Contact) {
                    replaceFragment(new ContactFragment());
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_Website) {
                    replaceFragment(new WebsiteFragment());
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_Facebook) {
                    replaceFragment(new FacebookFragment());
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_Copyright) {
                    replaceFragment(new CopyrightFragment());
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.menu,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


    }




Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
